# Updating 2 fields in google cloud firestore within a transaction

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a transaction that consists of one update operation and one set operation. From client side I am sending 2 concurrent requests to the transaction. The update operation is happening multiple times even though set did not succeed.

```
public addChatMessage(msg, callback, errorCallBack) {
        let msgColl = this.admin.firestore().collection('messages');
        var obj1 = JSON.parse(msg);
        var uid1 = obj1.message.senderID + "_"+obj1.message.senderLocalPostNo;
        this.admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc(uid1).get().then((docSnapshot) => {
            if (!docSnapshot.exists) {
                let metaRef = this.admin.firestore().doc('messages/msgsMeta');
                let msgRef = msgColl.doc(uid1);
                let transaction = this.admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {

                    return t.get(msgRef).then(a => {
                        return t.get(metaRef)
                        .then(doc => {
                            let newCounter = doc.data().counter + 1;
                            var finalResult = {message:obj1.message,serverPostNo:newCounter};
                            t.update(metaRef, {counter: newCounter});
                            t.set(msgRef, finalResult);
                        });
                    });

                }).then(result => {
                console.log('Transaction success', result);
                }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
                });
            } else {
                console.log("document already exists");
            }
        });
            console.log("EOF addChatMessage");
    }
```

I expected update operation to rollback if set operation could not happen, but it does not rollback.

Comment: That sounds weird indeed. Since you call the `t.update` and `t.set` on the same transaction, they should either both execute or neither of them should run. But the nesting in `this.admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc(uid1).get()` makes it harder to follow than I'd like. Can you: 1) reproduce the problem with just a transaction, and no other database interaction? 2) show the (wrong) result, for example by attaching a listener to the node and logging the values?